Rasbery Pi Pico bootsel file upload write error Buffer I/O error on dev sda1
I am really struggling to work out how to upload a boot sketch to a raspberry pi pico using ubuntu server 24.04
following instructions from the web I hold down the BOOTSEL button when I plug in the peco, then I upload my .uf2 file, then the drive automaticity unmounts itself from ubuntu and the peco boots itself up and runs the script.
I plug in the peco, nothing mounts but sda and sda1 show up in /dev so i
mount /dev/sda1 /media/pi
ls -ls /media/pi

there are 2 files INDEX.HTM and INFO_UF2.txt on the drive I amuse are default on all peco, they open with nano without any problem
so I upload my .uf2 file that just flashes the pico LED as a test script
cp /media/drive1/public/blinky.uf2 /media/pi

but after a few seconds I get error
[100445.522020] device offline error, dev sda, sector 260 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 pico class 0
[100445.535421] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 259, lost async write

If I ls into /media/pi I just get more errors
If I try to umount /media/pi its in use and wont umount and I have to force umount it with -l flag
If I re-plug and re-mount the pico, the same 2 default files are still there but not my .uf2 file
If I create a random file nano /media/pi/test.txt on the pico drive with nano and just write hi in the file, it does not error, I can re open the file and it still contains the text hi, but if I umount and mount the pico the file has vanished
since the contents of a .uf2 file is none asci I don't no how to paste it in with nano to see what happens since nano can save a text file to the drive even if the text file has a .uf2 extension it still rights to the drive
that leaves me wondering if it is anything to do with the auto unmount that tutorials clame the peco will do once you upload the sketch, rather than anything to do with righting the file to the drive.
other threads on the internet relating to Buffer I/O errors talk about things like power loss rather than mechanical fault, i have tried difference USB cables and better power supplies to the pi3 running ubuntu server but still get the same problem.
eater way I am falling short of answers on how to upload a sketch to a nano without getting Buffer I/O error logical block lost async write
I don't no what to try next to get a sketch to upload to the peco

maybe should i move this to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Seems it is only a hardware issue so I would say yes.

i have narrowed it down to only trying to upload uf2 files that were compiled on my HP elitebook laptop running ubuntu 22.04 so there must be something wrong with my CMake install on that laptop
